# Responsive Calculation

Tags: css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

It seems that to make responsive site, layout should be "Fluid". To make fluid layout many people use the width 90% . But suppose I design a site at 960 grid. so if I give the Width:960px; it will be stay exactly at 960px. So, it is very easy to calculate the width of other contents according to grid.

Unfortunately the frustrating moment is when I give 90% width to make responsive layout I see that the layout in browser is wider more than 960px. So, how can I calculate the layout according to 960px grid at 90% fluid layout width. ? Or what is the procedure regarding to calculating of width during build responsive design ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-width: 960px` to the wrapper and the layout will never be wider than that.